# ORA-00937: Not a single-group group function - Query error

Tags: database, oracle

**Error: ORA-00937: Not a single-group group function**

Query:

```
    select count(*) todas,
       sum(case when i.prioridade = 1 then 1 else 0 end) urgente,
       sum(case when i.prioridade = 2 then 1 else 0 end) alta,
       sum(case when i.prioridade = 3 then 1 else 0 end) normal,
       sum(case when i.prioridade = 4 then 1 else 0 end) baixa,
       (select count(*)
        from GMITEMOS i 
        inner join GMCTLSLA c  on c.os = i.cd_numero_os and c.item = i.item
        where i.situacao in ('A', 'I', 'P')
           and c.ordem = 99999
           ) naoAvaliados,
       sum(case when i.situacao = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) pendentes,
       sum(case when i.situacao = 'A' or i.situacao = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) iniciados
from GMITEMOS i 
where i.situacao in ('A', 'I', 'P')
   and  exists (select 1 
               from GMCTLSLA c 
               where c.os = i.cd_numero_os 
                  and c.item = i.item)
```

The error is ocurring here:

```
(select count(*)
        from GMITEMOS i 
        inner join GMCTLSLA c  on c.os = i.cd_numero_os and c.item = i.item
        where i.situacao in ('A', 'I', 'P')
           and c.ordem = 99999
           ) naoAvaliados
```

Can someone tell why is it happening?

Comment: Try put a single column into the group not *, or just group it by something that will be distinct anyway

Comment: Just fixed it with max(), thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have fixed it with `max` but that's not *why* it's happening and is a little bit hacky. Your problem is that your sub-query, which translates into a single column is not an aggregate query, `min`, `max`, `sum` etc and so needs to be included in a `group by` clause. You fixed this by wrapping it in `max` as the maximum of a single value will always be constant.

However, as your sub-query is, itself, an analytic query and will only ever return one row the obvious thing to do is to use a cartesian join to add it to your query. In the explicit join syntax this is known as the [`cross join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).

```
select count(*) todas
     , sum(case when i.prioridade = 1 then 1 else 0 end) urgente
     , sum(case when i.prioridade = 2 then 1 else 0 end) alta
     , sum(case when i.prioridade = 3 then 1 else 0 end) normal
     , sum(case when i.prioridade = 4 then 1 else 0 end) baixa
     , naoAvaliados
     , sum(case when i.situacao = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) pendentes
     , sum(case when i.situacao = 'A' or i.situacao = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) iniciados
  from GMITEMOS i 
 cross join (select count(*) as naoAvaliados
               from GMITEMOS j
              inner join GMCTLSLA k
                 on k.os = j.cd_numero_os 
                and k.item = j.item
              where j.situacao in ('A', 'I', 'P')
                and k.ordem = 99999
                    )
 where i.situacao in ('A', 'I', 'P')
   and exists (select 1 
                 from GMCTLSLA c 
                where c.os = i.cd_numero_os 
                  and c.item = i.item
                      )
```

The cartesian join has a bad reputation as it multiples the number of rows on one side of the join by the number of rows on the other. It does, however, have it's uses, especially in this sort of case.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because the subquery itself is a scalar result, not a group function. As you have apparently found, you can fix it by substituting a group function that yields an equivalent result to your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

In merge statement, if you are getting this error than simple use the group by and it will resolve the issue.

```
merge into table1 tb1
using
   (select a.id,a.ac_no,sum(a.qy) as qyt,sum(a.amt) as sum_amt from 
    table2 a, table1 b
    where a.id=b.id
    and a.id = '1234'
    and a.date = '08Oct2014'
    and a.ac_no in (123, 234, 345)
    and a.ac_no = b.ac_no
    group by a.ac_no,a.id
   )qry
  on (qry.id=tb1.id and qry.ac_no=tb1.ac_no )
  when matched then
  update set qy=qry.qy,amt = qry.sum_amt;
```